# QWebEngineView display position

Tags: qt

I used `QWebEngineView` to call html, and now I've shown success. however `QWebEngineView`  is shown in the upper left corner, I want to show `QWebEngineView`  in the white area below. First, I don't know how to do this step.Second, I don't know what kind of Qt should be used in the white area shown.Or you can provide me with a good tutorial to solve my current problem.

This is my interface:

[image]

The **bar chart** is the HTML file I want to display

This is the part of my code:

```
    pEngView = new QWebEngineView(this);
    pEngView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::NoContextMenu);
    pEngView->load(QUrl("file:///html/barx.html"));
    pEngView->show();
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Qt Designer and place a `QWidget` at the area you wanted. Then promote the `QWidget` to `QWebEngineView` and use the `ui` pointer to get pointer of the webengine widget. If you are new to Qt/QtDesigner follow the tutorials.

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html